# How to dynamically change Firefox Driver preferences in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to download multiple file and save into different locations

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
f   =new FirefoxDriver(profile);

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

//I want to change download dir name here with count**


}
```

Comment: one question - why are you setting `chrome.driver` if you are pointing to FireFox?

Comment: Selenium is a functional test utility. If you just want to download files, use something more appropriate, like [tag:wget].

Answer (score 0):

there are only a few ways you can do this. The download directory can't be changed once the driver has started, so there's always the option of downloading one file, restarting the driver, then downloading the other files in the same way.